# Given two integers N and M. How to check if N can be expressed as the sum of M raised to different integer powers?

Tags: algorithm, math, number-theory

I have two integers **N** and **M**. I have to check if **N** can be expressed as the sum of **M** raised to some **distinct** non-negative integer powers.

> **Example:** If **N** = 10 and **M** = 3, then answer is **YES**. Because, **10 = 3⁰ + 3²**
>
> If **N = 2** and **M = 3**, then the answer is **NO**.

**Remember**, I have to make sure that these powers must be **distinct**. How to approach this problem?

Comment: soo... the value `N` is composed of 1's and 0's when converted to base `M`?

Comment: @beaker yes..Do I just need to convert `N` to base  `M` and check if its composed of 1's and 0's?

Comment: @beaker That's great! thanks :)

Comment: If I stay on this site long enough I will fly through my next job interview.

Comment: Questions should have answers, that's important to the mission of stackoverflow.